# Проигрывание видео в элементе video со встроенного http-сервера на айоси

Tags: видео, ios, html5

Есть приложение на obj-c, в которое встроен http-сервер (использовался вот из [этого примера](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/MiniSOAP/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009323-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2), вроде почти без изменений,"вроде" т.к. весь проект мне в наследство достался), к которому идут запросы из UIWebView, в отображающемся html имеется тег video который не работает. Вопрос - какими свойствами должен обладать сервер чтобы видео проигрывалось.

Видео передается корректно, у него определены Content-type, content-length, Content-Range, то что это действительно так проверялось как с помощью загрузки видео NSURLConnection (заодно сохранил полученые данные в другое место и проверил что мд5 совпали), так и прямо в js с помощью XMLHttpRequest в том же месте где динамически добавлялся этот тег, в том же файле есть аудио и оно работает. Если страничку грузить из интернета то все хорошо, а вот с внутреннего сервера не хочет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам отвечу на свой вопрос, приведенный сервер не умеет показывать видео, но помогает вот этот [сервер](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer), только есть одна особенность - по какой-то причине в iOs 7 видео не будет проигрываться для localhost, надо использовать 127.0.0.1

На всякий случай уточню, что потомка NSURLConnection тоже пробовал, с ним не работает по крайней мере в 6 и - это известный баг.