# Показ видео в WEbView

Tags: ios, webview, видео

Пытаюсь показать видео в WebView используя код:

```
    NSURL *link = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://some/video/8b382aaba81c470497368ee5550e903b/"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:link];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
```

в результате чего получаю экран типа этого

[image: Imgur]

Как исправить или какая есть альтернатива подобному способу показывать видео напрямую из интернета?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько помню, компонент MPMoviePlayer умеет играть видео как с интернета, так и из локального файла. Другой вариант - попробуйте грузить видео не напрямую, а завернув его в html5 тег video.

В  целом причина насколько понимаю в том что есть какая-то хитрость что видео хапрашивается асинхронно и кусками по мере надобности и потому не срабатывает вариант подсунуть его все сразу. Когда-то возился [со встроенным сервером](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/262883/ios-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5-video-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-http-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8), там проблема была именно в запросе по кускам